# mysql more efficient way to query

Tags: mysql

below gets the job done but I feel like I am violating programming rule.

```
select *
from serverTable
where server like ‘proc1@server1’
order by reg_date desc
limit 1
union
select *
from serverTable
where server like ‘proc2@server1’
order by reg_date desc
limit 1
union
select *
from serverTable
where server like ‘proc3@server1’
order by reg_date desc
limit 1
union
select *
from serverTable
where server like ‘pro4@server1’
order by reg_date desc
limit 1
union
select *
from serverTable
where server like ‘proc5@server1’
order by reg_date desc
limit 1
```

Is there better way or correct way to get this done?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to find the maximum `reg_date` for each `server` group, where `server` can take one of the 5 values in your `UNION` query, and then select the full records from your table for each `server` group.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM serverTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT server,
           MAX(reg_date) AS reg_date
    FROM serverTable
    WHERE server in ('proc1@server1', 'proc2@server1', 'proc3@server1', 'proc4@server1', 'proc5@server1')
    GROUP BY server
) t2
    ON t1.server = t2.server AND
       t1.reg_date = t2.reg_date
```

Answer (score 0):

USE `UNION ALL` rather than `UNION`. By using `UNION`, the database is unnecessarily looking for duplicates that don't exist.  All of your UNIONed queries include a `WHERE` clause like "server like (some unique value)". `server` can't be equal to more than one of these, so you won't ever have any duplicates to filter out.

Also, use `=` instead of `like`. `LIKE` is used when you want to do a wildcard search, which you are not doing.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
select
  serverTable.col1,
  serverTable.col2,
  serverTable.col3,
  max(reg_date)
from
  serverTable
where
  server in ('proc1@server1','proc2@server1','proc3@server1','proc4@server1','proc5@server1')
group by
  serverTable.col1,
  serverTable.col2,
  serverTable.col3
order by
  server, reg_date;
```

Comment: sorry, I haven't had a chance to look at this. but will tonight and come back to this